# What object types should I use for testing generic collections?

Tags: c#, .net

What object types are best for writing unit tests for generic collections? Obviously if I'm using them in a specific way in my application, it's best to test with those types. But if I'm not, and simply creating a utility library, which types should I use?

I'm trying to avoid any pitfalls with specific object types. For example, when testing a generic dictionary structure, I know that the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods are very important in ensuring a valid test. I'm worried that if I simply use dummy `object` instances (`var a = new object();`), that I run into problems with these methods not being robust enough.

I'm considering using `GUID` instances for all of my unit testing, because of their necessarily unique constraints. However, being structs, I cannot test for equivalent references should I need to.

Lastly, are there any other gotchas to watch out for when using a specific object implementation (like `object` or `GUID`) in place of generic types for unit test purposes?

Comment: Very strange question.  Test in what way?  Unit test?  It depends what exactly you're testing, doesn't it?  If you need something that implements GetHashCode and Equals, then make sure you use something that does so.. you're just looking for a list of types that do?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone—I edited my question to specify unit testing and hopefully clarify my intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be thorough, you should test with several types:

1. A value type, such as `int`
2. A reference type which uses referential equality
3. A reference type with overridden `Equals`+`GetHashCode`
4. Passing in an `IEqualityComparer<T>`
5. `double` or `float` for their strange `NaN` semantics.

Not every test needs to be done for all of them. But I'd add at least one test for each of them.

Comment: +1. This looks like what I'm looking for. How would you implement `GetHashCode` for a reference type which uses referential equality? Also, can you explain what you meant by strange `NaN` semantics?

Comment: `How would you implement GetHashCode for a reference type which uses referential equality?` It is already implemented. No need to override.

Comment: So you're saying that the default `GetHashCode` implementation uses the object's reference?

Comment: When using `==` NaN is not equal to itself, whereas when using `Equals` it is. I believe older runtimes had some bugs related to that.

Comment: @DanRasmussen the default implementation(for reference types) returns a value that's constant over the lifetime of the object, and is consistent with referential equality. I believe it is somehow related to the syncblock in front of each object instance, but that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an ArrayList. populate it with custom objects, one of them being an integer like a primary key, and the others being your data. It is not a generic collection but very handy to use.

```
    class MyObject
    {
        public int myPrimaryKey {get; set;}
        public object myData {get; set;}
    {
```

Then all you have to do is add it to an ArrayList:

```
    var a = new ArrayList();
    a.add(new MyObject{myPrimaryKey = 1, object = 'some value'});
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Why `ArrayList`? It's unlikely that he's using .net 1.x. I see no reason to choose `ArrayList` over `List<object>`, apart from legacy scenarios. (Or some very specific scenarios)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting here.. How would this best test generic collections?

Answer (score -2):

If you mean that you want to test the generic collections from `System.Collections` namespace, then this is a wrong approach to testing.

Your test should cover your code only, but not other things which are not developed by you.

Comment: I'm developing my own collections library, which often utilize the `System.Collections` objects. (This should probably be a comment, anyways.)

Comment: Nope, this was suggested answer to correct your approach. which turned out not the case.